# How to run a thread from struts2

Tags: java, multithreading, jsp, servlets, struts2

i am developing a sturts2 webapplication, i am having a login page with username and password fields. As soon as user submitted form with values , i am validaing the login, if the user provides valid username and passoword, it is redirected to home page. While redirecting the home page, **i have to call a thread in  which i sets some data in session for future use**. How to do this ?

What i did is

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;

if( loginSuccess(userInfo) ) {
    initializeDatas(); // calling thread after userInfo bean validated
    // redirecting to home page
    return HOME_PAGE;
}
```

I have added a new class which implements runnable.

```
class intilalizer implements Runnable {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            System.out.println("Started to set values ");
            List<String> iphoneSdks = new ArrayList<String>();
            List<String> iphoneOSSdks = IosSdkUtil.getMacSdks(MacSdkType.iphoneos);
            List<String> simSdks = IosSdkUtil.getMacSdks(MacSdkType.iphonesimulator);
            List<String> macSdks = IosSdkUtil.getMacSdks(MacSdkType.macosx);
            iphoneSdks.addAll(iphoneOSSdks);
            iphoneSdks.addAll(simSdks);
            iphoneSdks.addAll(macSdks);

            ActionContext context = ActionContext.getContext();
            System.out.println("context ===> " + context); // here i am getting null value
            String httpRequest = ServletActionContext.HTTP_REQUEST;
            System.out.println("httpRequest =====> " + httpRequest);
            Object object = context.get(httpRequest);
            System.out.println(object);
            HttpServletRequest req = (HttpServletRequest) object;

            req.setAttribute(REQ_IPHONE_SDKS, iphoneSdks);
            req.setAttribute(REQ_IPHONE_SIMULATOR_SDKS, simSdks);
            System.out.println("Value initialized@@@@");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I am getting

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.photon.phresco.framework.actions.intilalizer.run(Login.java:286)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

I am getting this error on line .

```
ActionContext context = ActionContext.getContext();
System.out.println("context ===> " + context); // here i am getting null value
```

Comment: If `context` is null there's no way to tell what's going on from the code you posted.

Comment: Don't vandalise your questions 2 years after you asked them and long after people gratuitously helped you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From Struts 2 JavaDoc

> The ActionContext is thread local which means that values stored in the ActionContext are      unique per thread

You just create a new Thread so your ThreadLocal variables are not available there. You should do something like this:

```
import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionContext;

if( loginSuccess(userInfo) ) {
   ActionContext context = ActionContext.getContext(); 
   initializeDatas(context); // calling thread after userInfo bean validated
   // redirecting to home page
   return HOME_PAGE;
}
```

The best way will be pass context to Thread constructor. But I am not sure that COntext is ThreadSafe.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just wondering WHY do you need to start a new Thread to put some data in `session`

(thing that you say you wanna do, but that you actually don't do in the posted code, where you instead put stuff in `request`).

You can simply **[implement SessionAware Interface](http://struts.apache.org/2.3.4/struts2-core/apidocs/org/apache/struts2/interceptor/SessionAware.html)** from your Action(s).

> Actions that want access to the user's HTTP session attributes should
> implement this interface.
>
> This will give them access to a Map where they can put objects that
> can be made available to subsequent requests.
>
> Typical uses may be cached user data such as name, or a shopping cart.

It is not mandatory, but **[it is a best practice](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.14/docs/how-do-we-get-access-to-the-session.html)** for accessing session from within the Actions, instead of asking to ActionContext:

> You can obtain the session attributes by asking the ActionContext or
> implementing SessionAware. **Implementing SessionAware is preferred**.

If needed, here is a little example of usage: http://www.splinter.com.au/how-to-use-sessions-with-struts-2/

Answer (score 0):

```
if( loginSuccess(userInfo) ) {
    // redirecting to home page
    return HOME_PAGE;
    initializeDatas(); // calling thread after userInfo bean validated
}
```

That won't work. The method will end after the return call. Try calling the method that creates the new thread first.

```
if( loginSuccess(userInfo) ) {
    // redirecting to home page
    initializeDatas(); // calling thread after userInfo bean validated
    return HOME_PAGE;

}
```

Comment: @kaleeswaran14 Turns out you can cut-and-paste instead of typing it all over again.